# running `module M = ...` at the toplevel

Tags: ocaml

Learning OCaml is rapidly bringing me to the point of complete physical exhaustion...

In this page

https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html

it says

> In the ocaml toplevel, the following trick allows to visualize the contents of an existing module, such as List:

```
# module M = List;;
module M :
  sig
    val length : 'a list -> int
    val hd : 'a list -> 'a
    val tl : 'a list -> 'a list
    val nth : 'a list -> int -> 'a
    val rev : 'a list -> 'a list
    ...
```

When I type the exact same thing, character-by-character, at the toplevel, the only output I get is

```
module M = List
```

I.e., a helpful echo of what I just typed (minus the `;;`), which at least reassures me that the interpreter is not lost in some infinite loop.

What do I need to do to get the advertised behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "the toplevel"? There are several top-level environments at this point. In the standalone OCaml interpreter (CLI `ocaml` command) the `module M = List` trick works (and has for forever). You are possibly using something else, or have things in your `.ocamlinit` file that affect the behavior.

Comment: The one I tried was the one I get when I type `ocaml` at the CLI.  My `.ocamlinit` file is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This trick only works for older ocaml versions ( < 4.02.X )

With the latest ocaml version you have to use '#show_module' , e.g.

```
#show_module List ;;
```

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know this. I need to upgrade obviously. Using #show_module seems much more reasonable actually.

Comment: Thanks!  This is very helpful.  It is unfortunate/ironic that this works in the toplevels I get through `ocaml` and `utop`, but not the one I get through `coretop`: the module I wanted to inspect is a `Core` module, and `coretop` is the only toplevel I have found that does not barf at `open Core.Std`...  Two steps forwards, one step backwards, two steps forwards, one step backwards... (or is it the other way around?)

Comment: Just `#show` should be sufficient (it also works on type definitions).